# How to avoid mirroring background image for right to left languages

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, panorama-control

There is a background for my app which contains some texts on it.

So when the app loads for right to left languages, the image and its text gets mirrored which is not meaningful.

How can I avoid this? I like when it is right to left localization, the first item of the app, begin from the right of image to the left of it without mirroring.

(Sorry this is my first WP8 app!) It seems I should change `Panorama.Background` to not inherite right to left FlowDirection, But I don't know how!

Comment: Care to show how you are loading your app? Without seeing your code, diagnosing your problem becomes an exercise in speculation.

Comment: @Renan Com'on, It is a windows phone app, just change the background image of the default template for panorama.. which codes you are talking about?

Comment: It's just that five dollars say you are flipping the image on your own at some point. I'm not at home right now but I'm fairly sure I wouldn't be able to reproduce the problem if I tried hard. But reading your code, people here would be able to spot the problem.

Comment: If you're into workarounds, why don't you just use a flipped image when you load a right-to-left language?

Comment: Thanks @Renan. are you a windows phone developer?

Comment: Wouldn't call myself one, not just yet. But I'm trying to become one.

Comment: It really does help to know what you have tried already, show code/xaml explain what you are doing. [Be Specific](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).
That being said, did you try setting the FlowDirection of the Image?

Answer (score 0):

To get RTL you're probably setting `FlowDirection`. Do the same on the `Image`, but set it to LTR (you may need to edit the template if the background is part of a control, such as a `Panorama`).

You can see a ton more information about RTL in WP8 at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207040(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: thanks @Oren, I saw that link before, `Panorama.Background` needs an `ImageBrush` inside it, which neither one support `FlowDirection` nor `HorizontalAlignment`..